# I need to assign a role to visitors/guests

Tags: user-roles

Is there a way to create a 'role' in WordPress for a guest? I am using a role visibility plugin which lets me choose the type of visibility to each role. However a Guest hasn't got a role. I can create a role, however not sure how to link this to the "Guest"...

Comment: Custom roles are for users who are logged in only. Guests are defined as not being logged in. So … this is rather difficult. :)

Comment: This question relates to the use and configuration of a plugin and therefore would best be asked on the plugin authors forum. Otherwise, you can find answers already posted about how to create custom roles.

Comment: Yes, it does relate to a specific plugin, but the core of question is plugin-independent. I voted to leave it open.

Comment: Why does a guest need to have a role? You know that the guest is not logged in so why not just treat not-logged-in visitors differently rather than add the additional complexity of a role?

Answer (score 1):

Use add_role with any array of capabilities. Example:

```
add_role( 'custom_role', 'Custom Role', array( 'read' => true ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see 'guest' as a user role too actually. Anyhow, to get a guest, you can use this:

```
<?php
global $user_login;
if( $user_login ) {
echo 'user logged in';
} else {
echo 'user not logged in';
}
?>
```

And then you can add what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like you know what you are talking about - now to go one step further, I have the Members plugin by Justin Tadlock where I have created a 'role' named Visitor. How can I get the guest that you say I can find using that code to become this new "Visitor" role so I can then assign visibility to certain areas of the site etc? Not sure how to do this or where to put this code... thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know really... I am not familiar with the plugin, but you don't need to do that. You can use this code to do whatever you want to do with the visitor. It's the same as the member's guest.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you maybe use "User user Group Manager" named too "UAM".

I had recently the same problem.

The solution has several aspects which must be, each one, satisfied :

1- Create a general role with name like "custom-visitor" and allow only the rights of visitors

2- Into UAM you will now, when creating a new group appear your "custom-visitor". So you can create an UAM group which have only one role attached : "custom-visitor"

3- Now UAM must recognize a not logged in user as this "custom-visitor" and associate to him the role (which action is not done by WP)
This can be done by a patch of UAM :
into the init (or _construct class) you can add such a code (the "custom-visitor" is named "uam-visitor":

```
// ###trebly:b60119:hold user simply logged in as visitor role
    global $user_login, $wp_roles;
    $exist_visitor_role = false;
    foreach ($wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name) {
        if ($role == "uam-visitor") {
            $exist_visitor_role = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Anyway visitor role must be handled even have not been be permanently defined
    if (! $exist_visitor_role == true) {
        add_role('uam-visitor', 'Custom UAM visitor Role (WARNING: don\'forget to set the role permanently : default read all)', array('read' => true));
    }
    // If the visitor is not logged in he gets necessarily the custom "uam-visitor" role
    // ####trebly:CAREFULL:The problem is that some plugins can have checked no role for visitor : this must be checked
    // by $user_login or wp_get_current_user() and check and role empty
    // if role has been just set a Warning is displayed to upgrade because he has read all capability by default
    if( ! $user_login ) {
        // can have the role already set
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user->add_role('uam-visitor');
    }
```

**4- Now you can :**

a- attach elements to the UAM-visitor group : with this you will hide the needed elements to the visitor, but see these elements as admin for example.

b- but if you have another filter plugin, as it can run before UAM, it will not be able to check the role.
To solve this you must add to WP into user identification process (while not logged in) such instructions as :

```
        if( ! $user_login ) {
          // can have the role already set
          $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
          $current_user->add_role('custom-visitor');
        }
```

Best regards

Trebly

***Note about simulation of roles with WP*** : 
You can, in the same way, use this possibility to simulate your site behavior for a test visitor while a true visitor will not see the concerned elements. 
For this an UAM group is created with only a new role "testing-visitor" with no more rights than a visitor rights (except the fact to be attached to the UAM group which allows to hide elements to others : depending of the UAM corresponding parameter), then you creates a user with the "testing-visitor" role, after logged in he will see the elements which are hidden by UAM to others visitors.
When tests are successful, because you had created the "uam-visitor", you have just to switch the role of the UAM group to "uam-visitor" from "testing-visitor". Which action will give access to everybody (any not logged in : as defined in code) to the elements which remains nevertheless temporarily attached to the UAM-group. In this way you can switch all elements easily without changing anything to each one individually.

Later when you will set out the attachment of elements to the reserved UAM-group, then the element un-attached will be definitively visible by visitors (no more filter actionable for these elements). This is needed if you want to be able to repeat the operation with another group of elements (==components : post, pages, menu etc.) without creating another UAM-group and testing role. Several can be used but manage them can become quickly complex and source of bad errors of visibility.